# Yes I do. / Yes I have

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> A: I'm paying.
> B: You don't have any money.
> A: Yes I **do/have**.
> B: No you **don't/haven't**. Let me pay, OK?

I know that 'yes I do' and 'no you don't' are correct and natural, but would 'yes I have' and 'no you haven't' be correct and natural as well?

Comment: Are you asking because of the British and Irish tendency to use possessive "have" as an auxiliary verb, as in, "*Have you any idea*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we wish to contradict a negative statement containing an auxiliary verb, we use the same verb in the answer:

You **don't** (**do** not) have any money.
Yes I **do**.

You **don't** (do not) know how to ride a bicycle.
Yes I **do**.

You **won't** (will not) be able to see Grandma next week.
Yes I **will**.

You **can't** (cannot/can not) see the sea from here.
Yes you **can**.

Your conversation involving don't have/do have sounds American. A British conversation is more likely to be:

You **haven't** (have not) got any money.
More formally, we can say 'You **haven't** (have not) any money')
Yes I **have**.

Summary: in your answer, match the verb used in the statement you wish to contradict. To do otherwise results in the lack of naturalness that you wish to avoid.

Comment: +1 Correct, and to be clear, you match the *auxiliary* verb in the statement you wish to contradict.

Comment: People mistakenly say that **have got** is British. It ain't. And I don't believe for one second that Brits are more likely to use have got **all the time**. Or that NA speakers don't use it. English has two present tense verbs for have something: have and have got. In fact, the American usage of: You gotta car? Is really Have you got a car? which, depending on the situation, is also often said in full.

Comment: @Lambie - when I was a kid at a London local-authority (so not 'posh') infant and junior school (ages 5 to 11) the teachers did their best to eradicate 'have got' from our speech, without, it has to be said, much success. It was thought to be 'common' or 'vulgar'. I try not to use it, but slip sometimes. Other parts of the UK seem to say it less, e.g. Scotland.

Comment: Well, then, I don't understand the basis on which you claim the OP's conversation is US English. And you actually posted after that in your answer an example with "have got" saying it is more likely to be said that way in BrE. Can one have this both ways?

Comment: @Lambie - Americans are much more likely to say 'I don't have a car' and Brits to say 'I haven't got a car'.

Comment: No, that is not true. It simply isn't. We use have got all the time.  Believe me.

Comment: I'll second that. Both of those seem equally natural to my US ears.  Now without "got" it's a bit different.  "I haven't a car" still makes sense, but sounds awkward.  The only times I hear that is in certain phrases, used mostly for abstract things, like "I haven't a clue", "I haven't a care in the world", "I haven't a penny to my name", etc.  You wouldn't generally use it for something concrete and specific, like a car.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I see a singer called David Guetta has a song called _Family_ in which he sings 'I don't got friends, I got family'.

Comment: There's probably a generational and/or regional thing going on in the U.K.. I would likely say "I don't have a clue"; my mom "I haven't got a clue"; and I often hear "I haven't a clue," which would appear to be an attempt to avoid the much reviled "got"; but indeed that appears to apply to abstract ideas rather than objects. If I'm not mistaken I hear "I don't have a car" more often these days than "I haven't got a car" (in the U.S. everyone has a car so the point is moot).